# How to select a table in query as variable in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have mutliple tables with same name with added date in the last as abc_2016_09.

Now How can i call this mentioned statement, pls help.

```
SET @var = concat('ABC_table','_',date_format(curdate(), '%Y'),'_',date_format(curdate(), '%m'));
```

AND THEN

```
select * from @var
```

error code 1069 is coming.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @var = concat('abc_table','_',date_format(curdate(), '%Y_%m'));

SET @statment = concat('select * from ', @var);

PREPARE stmt FROM @statment; 
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Check it in mysql workbench, It does not return row in mariadb.

Comment: `date_format(curdate(), '%Y_%m')` is much simpler.

Comment: Yes sure...I have edited.